# What's the different about std::string to unsigned char[] and unsigned char*?

Tags: c++, string, unsigned-char

I get a string from the file, and i convert the string to unsinged char[].
This is my code:

```
unsigned char c[16];
std::string message = ReadFile(); // get string from file
strcpy((char*)c,message.c_str());
```

And convert the string to unsigned char*

```
unsigned char* c;
std::string message = ReadFile(); // get string from file
c = (unsigned char*)message.c_str();
```

I can't understand what the different about them. Are them the same?

Comment: `string` is a c++ object, while `char[]` is a c-style array. Using `char[]` in c++ is asking for troubles when in fact there is a much nicer solution.

Answer (score 6):

### The basics

`unsigned char c[16]`: `c` is an array of 16 `unsigned char`.

`unsigned char* c`: `c` is a pointer to an `unsigned char` (maybe to the beginning of a contiguous sequence (of unknown length) of `unsigned char`)

`std::string s`: `s` is a string object, which internally holds a contiguous sequence of characters whose length may vary dynamically. The string object also holds the current length of the string.

---

### First code sample

Here, you create a 16-character buffer, then create a `std::string` object, which you fill with the result of the `ReadFile` call.

You then request the C-string (null-terminated) representation of the `std::string` object, and use `strcpy` to copy it into the 16-char buffer. Unfortunately, you don't check the size, so it's **likely you'll overrun the end of the buffer** and stray into undefined behaviour. **Don't do this**. You now have two copies of the data; one in the `std::string`, and a (partial) copy in the 16-char array.

---

### Second code sample

In the second example, you once again assign the result of a `ReadFile` call into a `std::string`, and once again call the `c_str()` member function to request a null-terminated C-string representation. This time, you simply *cast* the resulting pointer such that its type is `unsigned char*`, and assign that to a pointer you've declared. You only have one copy of the data, and there's no buffer overrun.

However, if the contents of the string change, the pointer `c` may be invalidated.

---

### Guidelines

- Where possible, use `std::string` directly. Avoid passing around `char*` or using arrays of `char`, because `std::string` keeps track of the size, resizes as necessary, and handles the memory allocations for you.
- Don't do the first version. It's unsafe, because you don't check the bounds.
- Avoid the second version; if you have a function that takes a C-string, just give it the result of `s.c_str()` directly as an argument:

  ```
  void my_func(const char * str);

  // ...

  std::string s = "Hello";
  my_func(s.c_str()); // This is fine!
  ```

[Note: This assumes that your program is single-threaded and that the string `s` has local scope, i.e. is not visible for direct manipulation by `my_func` or anything that `my_func` can call. Any modification of `s` may invalidate the pointer returned by `s.c_str()`.]

- If you really need a copy of the content of a string, just assign it to another string before you make any changes:

  ```
  std::string s1 = "Hello";
  std::string s2 = s1; // copy the string
  s1 = "Goodbye";
  my_func(s2.c_str()); // still "Hello".
  ```

Comment: Your answer is useful.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same. First: you copy contents of `message` into `c`. And in second - you just assign pointer, that returns `c_str` to `c`. So, when message will be changed, or destroyed you will have garbage in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the string's content is copied into the array (although 16 is a fairly short length for a file buffer). And now you have two distinct containers that hold the same data.

In the second example, you read into the string and then pass the address of its container to the pointer. So the pointer would point to the same data as the string. However, you cannot convert from a const char * to a non-const type, so your example probably won't compile.

Is there any reason you convert to a c-style array in the first place?